# How can I access this value in an object inside an object from this Api response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native

So I'm trying to get the value of faceit_elo that is inside the csgo object
I've tried doing data.games.csgo.faceit_elo but it doesn't work.
Does anyone have an idea how to get this value?
Thank you!

[image: Api Response]

[image: My code]

Edit: Whenever I try to get the faceit_elo value, or just try to console.log(data.games.csgo), it just says process isn't defined. But when I try to get the value of avatar (data.avatar) there isn't any issue with that. I don't think there is an issue with the code, I just don't know how to access the faceit_elo

Edit:
I've figured out the error, it was on the setData(response), I had to change it to setData(response.games.csgo) so I could access the faceit_elo value.
This is for react-native.
As for a normal javascript app, you just get the value the same as javascript opjects.

Comment: you've posted an image of a javascript object - so, while you got that data from a "json file", forget JSON, it's just a regular javascript object, access values like any other javascript object - what is the issue when you try to access the value? "it doesn't work" is not useful information

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to make the request to the CS GO API?

I have a feeling that the start of your path with the data portion is perhaps not necessary, but it's impossible to know without the code actually making the request.

Comment: Please do not post screen shots of code. Post your code. Screen shots are not indexable by search engines and this question/answer will not be found by future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're getting the response as a JSON format.
Try this:

```
JSON.parse(data).games.csgo.faceit_elo
```